# Change folder names using Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have hundreds of folders with name format `ddmmyyyy`, eg. 21122011. But I want to change them into format `yyyy-mm-dd`, how to do it?

Comment: Would you be open to using PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume all folders in current directory have a name that follows ddmmyyyy as you specify.

Then this should rename those folders to yyyy-mm-dd

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%F in (*) do (
  set "folder=%%F"
  ren !folder! "!folder:~-4!-!folder:~2,2!-!folder:~0,2!"
)
```

It uses simple substring operations within variable expansion. Delayed expansion must be used because the variable expansion is occurring withn a block (within parentheses).